# Why can not get a vector class

Tags: r

I have extracted this dataframe:

```
> df<-as.data.frame(model_rf$variable.importance)
> df
                            Importance
DayOfWeek                 3.763932e+11
Customers                 1.364059e+12
Open                      6.345289e+11
Promo                     2.617495e+11
StateHoliday              5.196666e+09
SchoolHoliday             6.522969e+09
DateYear                  7.035399e+09
DateMonth                 2.013482e+10
DateDay                   3.763177e+10
DateWeek                  3.283496e+10
StoreType                 3.156843e+10
Assortment                2.025741e+10
CompetitionDistance       1.118476e+11
CompetitionOpenSinceMonth 4.633220e+10
CompetitionOpenSinceYear  4.554890e+10
Promo2                    0.000000e+00
Promo2SinceWeek           5.066674e+10
Promo2SinceYear           4.096407e+10
CompetitionOpen           3.992745e+10
PromoOpen                 2.831936e+10
IspromoinSales            2.844220e+09
```

then I want to extract values in other column:

```
> v<-as.vector(model_rf$variable.importance$Importance)
> v
 [1] 3.763932e+11 1.364059e+12 6.345289e+11 2.617495e+11 5.196666e+09 6.522969e+09 7.035399e+09 2.013482e+10 3.763177e+10
[10] 3.283496e+10 3.156843e+10 2.025741e+10 1.118476e+11 4.633220e+10 4.554890e+10 0.000000e+00 5.066674e+10 4.096407e+10
[19] 3.992745e+10 2.831936e+10 2.844220e+09
```

And names of each row in other column

```
> w<-(as.vector((row.names(df))))
> w
 [1] "DayOfWeek"                 "Customers"                 "Open"                      "Promo"                    
 [5] "StateHoliday"              "SchoolHoliday"             "DateYear"                  "DateMonth"                
 [9] "DateDay"                   "DateWeek"                  "StoreType"                 "Assortment"               
[13] "CompetitionDistance"       "CompetitionOpenSinceMonth" "CompetitionOpenSinceYear"  "Promo2"                   
[17] "Promo2SinceWeek"           "Promo2SinceYear"           "CompetitionOpen"           "PromoOpen"                
[21] "IspromoinSales"
```

Then I need to get a data frame created by the tow vector above:

```
DF<-as.data.frame(w,v)
```

> > DF<-as.data.frame(w,v) Warning message: In as.data.frame.vector(x, ..., nm = nm) :   'row.names' is not a character vector of length 21
> >     -- omitting it. Will be an error!

In fact, it seems that the w vector doesn't be converted as vector class even I did `as.vector`. It still as a `character` class.

```
> class(w)
[1] "character"
```

How do you explain this please?

Comment: R is vector based language. All base types are vectors, and `w` in your example.

Comment: @Aleh, So why I did not get  `DF` a data frame type? what's the error here?

Comment: what are you trying to do? Are you trying to construct new data.frame with two vars or ad column names to data.frame with `w` and `v` as column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
DF<-as.data.frame(cbind(w,v))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation of `as.data.frame` you see that the function expects the second vector to be a character vector for row names.

In your case, you supplied first the row names and then the values, leading to the error above.

You can either use

`as.data.frame(v,w)`

or

`data.frame(w,v)`

to get your desired result.